# Nested variable - problem with getting appropriate data - terraform

Tags: terraform, nested-loops

I have a problem with getting appropriate data from my object variable.
My variable definition looks as follows:

```
variable "auth0_org" {
  description = "List of organizations"
  default     = []
  type        = list(object({
    name                      = string
    display_name              = string
    db_name                   = list(string)
    logo_url                  = string
    colors_primary            = string
    colors_page_background    = string
    enable_auto_membership    = bool
    saml_config               = list(object({
      connection_name         = string
      strategy                = string
      sign_in_endpoint        = string
      sign_out_endpoint       = string
      sign_saml_request       = bool
      user_id_attribute       = string
      debug                   = bool
      signing_cert            = string
      enable_auto_membership  = bool
      fields_map              = object({
        email                 = string
        nickname              = string
        given_name            = string
        family_name           = string
      })
    }))
    openid_config             = list(object({
      connection_name         = string
      strategy                = string
      client_id               = string
      client_secret           = string
      scopes                  = list(string)
      discovery_url           = string
      type                    = string
      allowed_applications    = list(string)
    }))
  }))
}
```

Example data:

```
auth0_org = [
  {
    name                        = "abc"
    display_name                = "abc"
    db_name                     = []
    logo_url                    = "logo.png"
    colors_primary              = "#303EFA"
    colors_page_background      = "#0C204A"
    enable_auto_membership      = true
    saml_config                 = []
    openid_config               = [
      {
        connection_name         = "test-oidc"
        strategy                = "oidc"
        client_id               = "1234"
        client_secret           = "abc456"
        scopes                  = ["openid", "profile", "email"]
        discovery_url           = "https://okta.com/.well-known/openid-configuration"
        type                    = "front_channel"
        allowed_applications    = ["app01", "app02"]
      },
      {
        connection_name         = "test-oidc2"
        strategy                = "oidc"
        client_id               = "5678"
        client_secret           = "abc123"
        scopes                  = ["openid", "profile", "email"]
        discovery_url           = "https://okta.com/.well-known/openid-configuration"
        type                    = "front_channel"
        allowed_applications    = ["app01"]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to create OpenID connection in auth0:

```
resource "auth0_connection" "oidc" {
  for_each        = {
    for item in local.openid_configs : item.connection_name => item
  }
  enabled_clients     = ????
  options {
    client_id         = each.value.client_id
    client_secret     = each.value.client_secret
    scopes            = each.value.scopes
    discovery_url     = each.value.discovery_url
    type              = each.value.type
  }
}

locals {
  openid_configs = flatten([
    for org in var.auth0_org: [
      for openid in org.openid_config: {
        connection_name       = openid.connection_name
        strategy              = openid.strategy
        client_id             = openid.client_id
        client_secret         = openid.client_secret
        scopes                = openid.scopes
        discovery_url         = openid.discovery_url
        type                  = openid.type
        allowed_applications  = openid.allowed_applications
      }
    ]
  ])
  allowed_apps = flatten([  
    for app in local.openid_configs: app["allowed_applications"]
  ]
}
```

To be able to do that I need to specify applications IDs list in `enabled_clients`.
So far I have application names in my variable: `openid_config.allowed_applications` for example:

```
allowed_applications    = ["app01", "app02"]
```

Do you have any suggestion how can I do that?
I was trying to get this using data source like this:

```
data "auth0_client" "application" {
  for_each  = toset(local.allowed_apps)
  name      = each.value
}
```

But I don't know how to use this data source in `enabled_clients`.
Any suggestions are more than welcome.

---

(Update)

I've made few different attempts. It's working from code perspective but it's logically wrong. I think I should simplify my question.
In the code as a `enabled_clients` I can use `each.value.allowed_applications` like:

```
resource "auth0_connection" "oidc" {
  for_each        = {
    for item in local.openid_configs : item.connection_name => item
  }
  enabled_clients     = each.value.allowed_applications
  options {
    client_id         = each.value.client_id
    client_secret     = each.value.client_secret
    scopes            = each.value.scopes
    discovery_url     = each.value.discovery_url
    type              = each.value.type
  }
}
```

But this give me list of app names instead of its IDs: `["app01", "app02"]`.

Let's say also I have this kind of data structure:

```
allowed_apps_id = {
  app01 = "cbsdibcscbb2323"
  app02 = "cjsbsbsbxy666sa"
}
```

How to change the line:

```
enabled_clients     = each.value.allowed_applications
```

to get IDs instead of names?

Comment: Do you get any errors with your current code or attempt?

Comment: Hi Marcin :-)
I've edited my question a little bit. I don't know if that's helpful or not.

Comment: Thanks, but does your code run? Do you get any errors? If not, what exactly is the current outcome, and what would be the expected outcome?

Comment: My last attempt was to use as `enabled clients` this line of code:
`enabled_clients     = lookup(local.allowed_apps_ids, each.value.allowed_applications)`


I know that this is wrong and I'm getting the error:
`each.value.allowed_applications is list of string with 2 elements`
`Invalid value for "key" parameter: string required.`